# Proper file and folder layout .NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET 4.8 MVC project, I have an infrastructure and models folders.  What should go in each folder?

For example, if I have a class named Car, would all properties, constructors, methods, everything related to a car go in a Car.cs file in the Models folder, or would some of it go in the Infrastructure folder?

Answer (score 1):

Models - All the POCO classes which are used to create a table when using code first approach.

Infrastructure - Includes database repository interfaces and their implementations which will have methods that directly Add, Update, Delete records in database tables etc.